# php mkdir() chmod and permissions

Tags: php, mkdir

i was using this basic script:

```
$folderPath = "../path/to/$folder/";
mkdir("$folderPath");
```

i create this directory and then upload photos to it. I've been doing this for a good 4-5 months now and suddenly i start getting 'FORBIDDEN' errors when I attempt to view the contents of the folder via web browser

The directory is being created the same and the photos are still uploading without a problem, but I cannot access the photos

I tried rewriting the script and using chmod to change the permissions but I'm having no luck at all

All the older folders were being created with: -w- rwx r-x r-x

and I can't get this recreated

I've tried adding a chmod line into my script:

```
$folderPath = "../sales/inventory/$folder/";
mkdir("$folderPath");
chmod("$folderPath", 0755);
```

but I can't recreate the same permissions, I'm trying to understand how chmod works, but I can't figure out how to get this very basic function working properly again

Comment: accept some answers if you want people to help you

Comment: This code sort of unnerves me, are you sanitizing/filtering `$folder`? If not, that would be my first guess as to why it stopped, a potential security breech.

Comment: this isn't the whole script i have filters on $folder

Comment: Just checking, as that could have been a (or the) problem. Did you check the actual permissions of the photos? As if you have access to the folder, that is part of it, the photos also need proper permission.

Comment: sounds like a provider thing, safe mode is unlikely, quota, or possibly fastcgi + suexec, ask on serverfault; the presented code isn't the cause

Comment: What is chmod() returning? If the permissions are wrong, PHP may be unable to change the permissions; this would show up as the chmod() call returning FALSE. Is the server running a Unix-type OS? If so, and if you have shell or (S)FTP access, do a directory listing with permissions and show us the output. (On the shell, do a `ls -la` while inside the directory.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try looking out for a HTAccess file, where the "Options -Indexes" option will be mentioned, as this is mostly used for not showing the contents of a folder in a web browser. The file needs to be searched in the following manner:-

- In the folder "`root_folder/sales/inventory/$folder/`", where "`$folder`" is as mentioned in your code.
- If not found, try in the folder "root_folder/sales/inventory/".
- If not found, try in the folder "root_folder/sales/".
- If not found, try in the folder "root_folder/".

When you get the code of "Options -Indexes" written in the HTAccess file, you can remove / comment that line of code from there, or you can also write another HTAccess file in your required folder of "`$folder`", where the code will be "Options Indexes".

Also in the PHP page, the logic must be like this:-

```
<?php
$folderPath = "../sales/inventory/$folder/";
mkdir("$folderPath");
chmod("$folderPath", 0755);

// Use of "copy()" / "move_uploaded_file()" function here, using some "$targetFile" variable.
chmod($targetFile, 0755);
?>
```

This will help you when you will be unlinking / deleting the uploaded files from the "$folder" folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help, this does help but I'm still having a problem with the actual permissions reflecting what I plug into the script, for example your example works fine except that when I look at the permissions from the directory tree, the created $folder isn't rwx r-x r-x as should be expected, but instead comes out as rwx r-x ---

Comment: on second thought i Just reread what you said and I must have missed the chmod on the upload files part at the end, I tried adding that to the upload script and it works fine.  I really appreciate the help everything seems to be working alright, for now I just can't figure out why this broke in the first place

Comment: @thomas - It's a common part, which I also did this wrong thing, when I myself was a fresher. So nothing to worry about & cheer up! **Best of Luck!!!**

Answer (score 8):

If your $folder variable includes some sub-directories your parent directories are maybe not being chmoded to the right permissions. This was the problem I was having on a hired OVH Gentoo server.

Imagine that `$folder = '/store1/ally23/shelf42';` so your final directory structure is 
 `../sales/inventory/store1/ally23/shelf42`, and you want `0777` permisions.
You do:

```
mkdir($folderPath, 0777, true) || chmod($folderPath, 0777);
```

Only the final directory `shelf42` is chmoded to `0777`. The intermediary directories are created with default permissions (in my case `0744`).

There is no recursive option in PHP's chmod command, so you have to loop over the intermediary directories and chmod them individually.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a shared environment, you may also want to [**chown**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) after upload, to be on the safe side. Especially if you're running your web server under a user other than your virtual host has permission to access (EG: "nobody" vs "mysite".) This is common with cPanel servers, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Simply umask means the default permissions for new files/directories:

```
<?php
 umask(022);
?>
```

This sets the default permissions for user, groups, and others respectively:

- 0 - read, write and execute
- 1 - read and write
- 2 - read and execute
- 3 - read only
- 4 - write and execute
- 5 - write only
- 6 - execute only
- 7 - no permissions